# How can i code a system of ODE with one condition in scilab?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, simulation

I have a probleme when i code my system in scilab

Normally i write systems with only ODE like
$$ \left \{
\begin{array}{rcl}
\frac{dx}{dt}&=&a*x+b \\
\frac{dy}{dt}&=&b*y*x+c*y
\end{array}
\right.$$

But this time i have also something like that

$$\left \{\begin{array}{rcl}
\frac{dx}{dt}&=&a*x+b \\
\frac{dy}{dt}&=&b*y*x+c*y \\
z&=&1-x-y
\end{array}
\right.$$

For the first sysem i use :

```
function xdot=func(t,x)

xdot(1)=a*x(1)+b

xdot(2)=b*x(2)*x(1)+c*x(2)

endfunction
```

But for the secon system this not ive the correct result

```
function xdot=func(t,x)

xdot(1)=a*x(1)+b

xdot(2)=b*x(2)*x(1)+c*x(2)

xdot(3)=1-xdot(1)-xdot(2)
endfunction
```

This question is surely basic but impossible to find th answer

Thank you for your help

Comment: The last equation in the second system is just an algebraic equation.

Comment: The derivative of a constant is zero.  // You could check if the solvers with implicit methods, the ones recommended for stiff systems, also have DAE capabilities.

Comment: yes sorry i write xdot(3)=-xdot(1)-xdot(2) but this doesn't work too